# Compare Date object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate

I have this date object from Parse, `"2015-07-24 20:36:38 +0000"` and I would like to compare it to today's date to see how much time has passed since the date on the date object. Any ideas how to do this?

I have this method I use to get the hour and minute, but I'm stuck on how to use this to compare dates outside of the current day.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];

NSString *formattedTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `NSTimeInterval` for this, the code is:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

with date being the date from parse as an `NSDate`, not `NSString`. and there should be no need to format it before comparing. Hope this helps

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is not an object. You don't want that `*` there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this formatted as a string, in iOS 8 and later you can use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`:

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitHour;
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:date toDate:[NSDate date]];
```